# How to generate a report of IIS settings for easy perusal?

Tags: iis

I'm looking for a way to (hopefully) create a text file which lists all the settings in IIS for..

- Virtual Directories
- Web sites
- Which framework is used on a certain website/directory
- directory of hosted files
- etc.

Basically I want to do some investigation on some of our servers to figure out where certain projects are located, without digging through right clicking and looking for the directory name manually, etc, for every domain we host.

The reasoning is that I often need to find access to files/projects I haven't worked on before, but historically, we don't have a strong naming scheme, so you can't just look where something "logically" would be - so, generating a list would be very helpful.

Something like this would be awesome, but I'm looking for any tips at all

- Domainname1.com

  - framework: ASP.NET 1.1
  - directory: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\domainname1.com
  - Applications hosted at this domain:

etc, etc.

Plain text, XLS, XML.. anything other than right clicking through the whole list!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS metabase is a configuration file that contains most of the settings of IIS, including what websites/application pools are running on the server.  It's located by default at:

%windir%/system32/inetsrv/metabase.xml

You can potentially use that as a starting point and write a custom parser, or an XSLT transformation to get the report you want, but it's probably not going to be a trivial task.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I needed, even though it will be hard to parse.  I can at least ctrl-F through it and find the clues I am looking for.  Thanks!